# Regex search for strings like "150/2"

Tags: regex

I'm using VB 2010 and Regex to find a text of the pattern "[number]/[number]" in a HTML block. What regex search pattern should I use? Thanks !

Comment: May number be negative? Hexadecimal? Floating point? Scientific notation? Octal? Leading zeros?

Comment: [3 digit +ve number]/[2 digit +ve number which must be less than 11]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\d+)\s*\/\s*(\d+)
```

Explanation:

```
(\d+): One or more digits. Captured in first group.
\s*  : Zero or more space like chars
\/   : The `/`. Escaped.
\s*  : Zero or more space like chars
(\d+): One or more digits. Captured in second group.
```